# QtCreator doesn't start on Wayland

Tags: qt, debian, gnome, wayland, qtwayland

I'm using Wayland session on Debian 11 (sid).
Installed QtCreator from their website via .sh script but it doesn't launch. When running from '~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin' directory in the terminal I get:

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. qt.qpa.plugin: Could
> not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" This application
> failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
> offscreen, vnc, xcb.
>
> Aborted

Tried

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland ./qtcreator
```

and

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland 
./qtcreator
```

and

```
./qtcreator --platform=wayland
```

Also tried installing qt 6.0.3 and 5.15.

No luck, qtcreator doesn't launch.

Comment: welcome to [so], a programmer's forum. it seems your question is not related to programming at all, so you probably should ask on [su] instead. (just because the program you try to launch happens to be development related doesn't make the question a programming question; if the harddisk on your development computer dies, resurrecting it won't be a programming question either)

Comment: Try installing the package qt5-wayland if it not already installed.

Comment: @umläute, From [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow __unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.__ (the emphasis is mine). I kindly suggest you to retract your close vote.